# React Native fetch API error - page keeps refreshing

Tags: api, react-native

I'm trying to fetch [this](https://rapidapi.com/KishCom/api/covid-19-coronavirus-statistics) api into my android app. However, the emulator screen keeps loading. Can somebody please point out the error?

[Check code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhiZ8.png)

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` is returning without handling the Promise.

You don't have to return anything in `componentDidMount` anyway. So you can just have

```js
componentDidMount() {
 fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then((jsonRes) => {})
}
```

Or use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await)